# error when ionic cordova run android in ionic

Tags: android, angular, cordova, build, ionic3

**error in my terminal**

Android Studio project detected

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\FUJIN\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\FUJIN\hilih\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 68
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.

  > No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
(node:15572) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\FUJIN\hilih\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 68
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.

  > No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

> BUILD FAILED in 0s
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\FUJIN\hilih\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:180:13)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:936:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5) (node:15572)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:15572) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. [02:00:48]  lint finished
>   in 4.01 s

[OK] Your app has been deployed.
     Did you know you can live-reload changes from your app with --livereload?